# What is Golang base64 Session Description in pion/webrtc/examples?

Tags: go, webrtc

My goal is to communicate between 2 parties without using the server to broadcast the data. I believe WebRTC is the solution.

So, I tried to learn WebRTC, starting from `pion/webrtc`. However, the examples did not work`-ish`.

My understanding is that:

1. `a listener need the SDP to subscribe to a broadcaster`.

What I did:

1. download `github.com/pion/webrtc` in zip, unzip it and copy the `examples` folder to `learn-golang-webrtc/examples`.
2. `go mod init github.com/kidfrom/learn-golang-webrtc`
3. `$ go get github.com/pion/webrtc`
4. `$ cd examples && go run examples.go`
5. go to `localhost` and then click the `broadcast` menu.
6. click the button `Publish a Broadcast`, the video started.
7. click the button `Copy browser SDP to clipboard`.
8. open new tab to `localhost` and then click the `broadcast` menu.
9. click the button `Join a Broadcast`
10. paste the clipboard to the `Golang base64 Session Description`.
11. click the button `Start Session`.

The problem:

1. The video does not start and just show loading icon.

[image: The listener view]

Answer (score 0):

"github.com/pion/mediadevices/pkg/codec/vpx"

import the vpx package instead of x264 and try the following code.

// Create a new RTCPeerConnection

```
x264Params, err := vpx.NewVP8Params()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

this will works :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).